# Directory.Exists returns true when "dsdasdad" is passed

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, directory, exists

I don't know why when I try to check if my directory exists like this:

```
Directory.Exists(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text)
```

It always returns **true** .

When I pass explicitly a string, e.g. like this:

```
Directory.Exists("dsdasdad")
```

It works fine and returns **false**.

I tried to do it like this :

```
string textFromTextBox = Convert.ToString(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text);
Directory.Exists(textFromTextBox );
```

and it returns **true** again.

Comment: What does the Debugger say?

Comment: Is your debug folder having a folder with the name you mention in the textbox.

Comment: The variable (in your title) doesn't match the substituted literal.

Comment: For the example given above it says that:
Directory.Exists(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text) = true . But it doesn't really test the real value which has to be:
Directory.Exists("dasdasdas") because this is what I have entered in the myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.

Comment: How are you using the boolean value? Is it possible that the method actually returns `false`, but it seems like it would return `true` because something is happening that you think only would happen then?

Comment: Just to also point out that your title specifies the text `dsdasdad` and your code indicates that you are explictly checking for `dsadasda` (they are quite different).  Might be worth checking that you have the same text in the `TextBox` and your explicit check.

Comment: @Guffa I am using it in if-statement.Just a regular use.
if(!Directory.Exists(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text)) - > Do something.
I just enter the path to the folder in a text box and then I test it if it actualy exists on my file system.

Comment: @MartinParkin : they both don't exist.The result must be false for both.I just randomly typed those values.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik I do appreciate that they are random pieces of text, I am simply pointing out that unless you are testing for the same text explicitly and in your `TextBox`, you could inadvertantly be getting an inconsistent result :)

Comment: Did you create your textbox in runtime?

Comment: @MartinParkin No, it is not hard-coded. I was just testing it with that explicit use of it.Just for debugging to see how the value is being passed in the parameter.And it is weird that when I pass it explicitly it works and everything is OK.But when I pass something that has to be calculated on runtime it doesn't pass the calculated value but only the declaration of the operator as I pointed it out in the example given above:
Directory.Exists(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text) .
This is supposed to be :
Directory.Exists("dsdasdad") , because it is the return value.

Comment: @Rezoan No, I did it in advantage with the designer and it is static.

Comment: Can you post ALL your code ?

Comment: Just reminding. Please make sure to check your projects exact output/working directory for such kind of folder. and try to replace myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text with myTextBox_TextBox.Text.  if the textbox is on the same form where you are checking, instance of myForm makes no seance. also you don't need to convert a textbox text to string when it is already a string but you can trim it and let me know the updates. @mathinvalidnik

Comment: @Rezoan I checked the working folder and I tried without the myForm in
 myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text.This is not the reason.There is something else I guess.

Comment: does it returns true for only "dsdasdad"? and could you please try to run the exe in another machine or VM (if any). and see if the problem still exist.

Comment: also check with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath it will give you a string output of your assembly path/ current working directory. and see there exist folder "dsdasdad"
You can also check with Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"bin") 
Just remember if programm says there is a directory exist with that name it is exist (there is no doubt)
@mathinvalidnik

Comment: @Rezoan How could it exist when I am typing it right before the check is being performed? I start the aplication and there is a text box where I type something that makes no sense and doesn't exist on my file system at all(e.g. "dsdlasjdlasjdkasjd").Obviously, this is not a directory on my computer.After that I push a button that performs the testing with Directory.Exists. There is no place where that directory could be even created.This is not the problem , I am 100% sure.

Comment: did you test with different machine? @mathinvalidnik. and can you please put your all source code here?

Comment: Either your application isn't compiling and isn't running the code you think it is, or the value of the text box isn't what you think it is, or the directory really does exist which might mean your current directory is not what you think it is. To test all three, try adding a line like `MessageBox.Show(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text  + " " + Directory.Exists(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text) + " " + new DirectoryInfo(myForm.myTextBox_TextBox.Text).FullName);`  and see what it outputs.